# Parallel downloading don't work in python threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, download

I'm building a parallel download library using `threading` module.

When I use my library, it downloads the file without error, but **the video file doesn't have the same content as if I downloaded it through the browser**.

I use `threading` for parallel downloading and I think I have a problem with `threading.Lock` and `file.seek`, but I can't figure out how to fix the problem.

This is my code:

```
import requests
import threading
from tqdm import tqdm

DOWNLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE = 1 << 20 # 1 MiB

class DownloadPart:
    def __init__(self, url, byte_range) -> None:
        self.url = url
        self.byte_range = byte_range

        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def download(self, file, pbar=None):
        response = requests.get(
            self.url,
            headers={"Range": "bytes={}-{}".format(*self.byte_range)},
            allow_redirects=True,
            stream=True,
        )

        written = 0

        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=DOWNLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk:
                self.lock.acquire()

                file.seek(self.byte_range[0] + written)
                length = file.write(chunk)
                file.flush()

                written += length
                pbar.update(length)

                self.lock.release()


class Downloader:
    def __init__(self, url, parts=10):
        self.url = url
        self.parts = parts

    def _get_file_size(self) -> int:
        info = requests.head(self.url, allow_redirects=True)

        info.raise_for_status()

        size = info.headers.get("content-length", None)
        assert size
        return int(size)

    def download(self, filename):
        file_size = self._get_file_size()
        # file_size = 1024

        size_per_part = file_size // self.parts

        print(file_size, size_per_part)

        file = open(filename, "wb")

        pbar = tqdm(total=file_size)

        threads = []
        for index in range(self.parts):
            # fix last part have more bytes
            if index + 1 == self.parts:
                byte_range = (size_per_part * index, file_size - 1)
            else:
                byte_range = (size_per_part * index, size_per_part * (index + 1) - 1)

            thread = threading.Thread(
                target=DownloadPart(self.url, byte_range).download, args=(file,), kwargs={"pbar": pbar}
            )
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()

        file.close()


URL = "https://s-delivery38.mxdcontent.net/v/8a5f59673042ed97c402be84ceeb20d9.mp4?s=TfiDzO2oBLrhub_GhToCiQ&e=1676489987&_t=1676476332"

d = Downloader(URL)

d.download("video.mp4")
```

How can I solve the problem with my library and **get the same data in the file**? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems with my code:

1. I found a solution to the first problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25165183/14900791:

> The `Lock()` function creates an entirely new lock - one that only the
> thread calling the function can use. That's why it doesn't work,
> because each thread is locking an entirely different lock.

2. Mixdrop (`mxdcontent.net`) only allows two videos in the same ip, so the code only works for two parts, the others got status code `509` (I didn't checked the status code so I didn't get an error).

```py
import requests
import threading
from tqdm import tqdm

DOWNLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE = 1 << 20 # 1 MiB

# global lock instance
lock = threading.Lock()

class DownloadPart:
    def __init__(self, url, byte_range) -> None:
        self.url = url
        self.byte_range = byte_range

    def download(self, file, pbar=None):
        response = requests.get(
            self.url,
            headers={"Range": "bytes={}-{}".format(*self.byte_range)},
            allow_redirects=True,
            stream=True,
        )

        written = 0

        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=DOWNLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE):
            if chunk:
                lock.acquire()

                file.seek(self.byte_range[0] + written)
                length = file.write(chunk)
                file.flush()

                written += length
                pbar.update(length)

                lock.release()


class Downloader:
    def __init__(self, url, parts=10):
        self.url = url
        self.parts = parts

    def _get_file_size(self) -> int:
        info = requests.head(self.url, allow_redirects=True)

        info.raise_for_status()

        size = info.headers.get("content-length", None)
        assert size
        return int(size)

    def download(self, filename):
        file_size = self._get_file_size()
        # file_size = 1024

        size_per_part = file_size // self.parts

        print(file_size, size_per_part)

        file = open(filename, "wb")

        pbar = tqdm(total=file_size)

        threads = []
        for index in range(self.parts):
            # fix last part have more bytes
            if index + 1 == self.parts:
                byte_range = (size_per_part * index, file_size - 1)
            else:
                byte_range = (size_per_part * index, size_per_part * (index + 1) - 1)

            thread = threading.Thread(
                target=DownloadPart(self.url, byte_range).download, args=(file,), kwargs={"pbar": pbar}
            )
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()

        file.close()


URL = "https://s-delivery38.mxdcontent.net/v/8a5f59673042ed97c402be84ceeb20d9.mp4?s=TfiDzO2oBLrhub_GhToCiQ&e=1676489987&_t=1676476332"

d = Downloader(URL)

d.download("video.mp4")
```